# What does it mean in HTML 5 when an attribute is a boolean attribute?

Tags: html

What does it mean when an attribute like the hidden attribute is a boolean attribute? Can someone explain this in layman's terms?

Comment: Related post - [Radio button is checked by default when checked property is false?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54211154/465053)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

> 2.5.2 Boolean attributes
>
> A number of attributes are boolean attributes. The presence of a
>   boolean attribute on an element represents the true value, and the
>   absence of the attribute represents the false value.
>
> If the attribute is present, its value must either be the empty string
>   or a value that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the attribute's
>   canonical name, with no leading or trailing whitespace.
>
> The values "true" and "false" are not allowed on boolean attributes.
>   To represent a false value, the attribute has to be omitted
>   altogether.

Comment: I guess I am confused how the other answer is the correct answer. I'll let the author choose.

Comment: Boolean attributes pre-html5 are either present or not; foo="false" and foo="true" are thus equivalent (and true).  With html5, they should no longer have arbitrary values (thus keeping people from the foo="false" error) but must be either foo="" or foo="foo" (both true).

Answer (score 110):

As already stated boolean attributes are attributes that are evaluated either true or false.

However, from HTML5 Spec - http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attributes

> **2.5.2 Boolean attributes**
>
> A number of attributes are boolean attributes. The presence of a
> boolean attribute on an element
> represents the true value, and the
> absence of the attribute represents
> the false value.
>
> If the attribute is present, its value must either be the empty string
> or a value that is an ASCII
> case-insensitive match for the
> attribute's canonical name, with no
> leading or trailing whitespace.
>
> The values "true" and "false" are not allowed on boolean attributes. To
> represent a false value, the attribute
> has to be omitted altogether.

Note that this means that `<div hidden="true">` is **not** allowed in HTML5.

Correct would be either `<div hidden>` or `<div hidden="">` or `<div hidden="hidden">` or case-insensitive and single quotes/unquoted variations of any of them. All of these would evaluate to `true`.

Only when the attribute is missing completely is it considered `false`.

Comment: Doesn't middle paragraph of 2.5.2 mean that <div hidden>, without attribute value, is also disallowed? Although the examples in the spec show that attribute name without value is valid syntax.

Comment: @croraf - Section 2.5.2, like most of the normative text of the HTML5 spec, applies equally to the HTML and XHTML syntaxes. But an attribute without an attribute value is allowed in the HTML syntax but not in the XHTML syntax. So we have to look in section 8 of the spec "The HTML syntax". There it says in [8.1.2.3 Attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attributes-0) that the first of the 4 ways to specify attributes is "Empty attribute syntax:  Just the attribute name. The value is implicitly the empty string." The implicit value complies with the middle paragraph.

Comment: Allowed or not, browsers don't actually enforce this part of the spec in any way. `hidden="false"` will evaluate the same as `hidden` and `hidden="hidden"` in practice. (What should they do with `hidden="false"` instead? )

Answer (score 5):

As the others said, a Boolean has three possible syntax for **true**:

```
<textarea readonly></textarea>
<textarea readonly=""></textarea>
<textarea readonly="readonly"></textarea>
```

And one for **false**:

```
<textarea></textarea>
```

Except that you have a few exceptions like this one, obviously:

> **spellcheck [HTML5]**
>
> Setting the value of this attribute to true indicates that the element needs to have its spelling and grammar checked. The value default indicates that the element is to act according to a default behavior, possibly based on the parent element's own spellcheck value. The value false indicates that the element should not be checked.

Comment: That isn't an exception. `spellcheck` is not a boolean attribute.

Comment: Ah, yes. "true" and "false" are the new Not Boolean. Agreed.

Comment: It's an enumerated attribute that can take the values "true", "false", or "default".

Comment: Upvote for the observation that the only way to specify **false** is to omit the Boolean attribute.

Answer (score 1):

**A.** Based on the comment of Bob.at.Indigo.Health:

With some html attribute that should represents a boolean value (e.g. `checked` attribute for checkbox) ...the **only way to set it to** `false` is to **omit the attribute**, :

```
<input type="checkbox"  />
```

All other assignments will be interpreted as `true` (even if that does not follow html standard), e. g.

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked"/> 
<input type="checkbox" checked=undefined />
<input type="checkbox" checked=null/>
<input type="checkbox" checked=false/>
<input type="checkbox" checked="false"/>
<input type="checkbox" checked=""/>
<input type="checkbox" checked="foo"/>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hgq4ewr1/

**B.** Some **JavaScript** libraries might define special values that are also interpreted as false.

With d3.js you can for example remove attributes ("set them to false") by calling the `attr` function with `null`:

```
d3Selection.attr('checked', null);
```

The [getAttribute](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getattribute.asp) Method of HTMLElement returns `null` or `''` if the
attribute does not exist.

Also see:

- [How to remove an attribute in D3.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15322556/how-to-remove-an-attribute-in-d3-js)
- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_checked.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getattribute.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp
- [checked = "checked" vs checked = true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10650233/checked-checked-vs-checked-true)

**C.** If you inherit from `HTMLElement` in **JavaScript**, you are able to define custom attributes of different type than String. Also see https://www.webcomponents.org/introduction

However, I would call those JavaScript attributes and not HTML attributes, e.g:

```
<html>
    <head>      
        <script>
            class TreezElement extends HTMLElement {

                static get observedAttributes() {
                    return ['value'];
                }

                                
                get valueProperty() {
                  var stringValue = this.getAttribute('value')
                  return this.convertFromStringValue(stringValue);
                }

                set valueProperty(newValue) {
                  var stringValue = this.convertToStringValue(newValue)
                  if(stringValue === null){
                      this.removeAttribute('value');
                   } else {
                      this.setAttribute('value', stringValue);    
                   }
                }               

                constructor(){
                    super();                        
                } 
                
                //should be overridden by inheriting class
               convertFromStringValue(stringValue){                     
                    return stringValue;
                }

                //should be overridden by inheriting class
                //return null if the value attribute should be removed
                //(="set to false")
                convertToStringValue(value){
                    
                    return value;
                }
                
                updateElements(newValue){
                    //should be implemented by inheriting class
                }

                
                attributeChangedCallback(attr, oldValue, newValue) {
                     if(attr==='value'){                                                
                        if(newValue!==oldValue){    
                            this.updateElements(newValue);                          
                            this.__dispatchInputEvent();
                        }
                     } 

                              
                }       
                
                

            }
        </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> 2.4.2. Boolean attributes
>
> A number of attributes are boolean attributes. The presence of a
>   boolean attribute on an element represents the true value, and the
>   absence of the attribute represents the false value.
>
> If the attribute is present, its value must either be the empty string
>   or a value that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the attribute’s
>   canonical name, with no leading or trailing white space. The values
>   "true" and "false" are not allowed on boolean attributes. To represent
>   a false value, the attribute has to be omitted altogether.

Example:
Here is an example of a checkbox that is checked and disabled. The checked and disabled attributes are the boolean attributes.

```
<label><input type=checkbox checked name=cheese disabled> Cheese</label>
```

This could be equivalently written as this:

```
<label><input type=checkbox checked=checked name=cheese disabled=disabled> Cheese</label>
```

You can also mix styles; the following is still equivalent:

```
<label><input type='checkbox' checked name=cheese disabled=""> Cheese</label>
```

check this post [Boolean HTML Attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706384/boolean-html-attributes) it may help you as well.