# checked = "checked" vs checked = true

Tags: javascript, html

What is the difference between the below two usages?

```
document.getElementById('myRadio').checked = "checked";
```

and

```
document.getElementById('myRadio').checked = true;
```

For me, both are behaving the same way. But, I am just curious to know why there exist two methods to do the same.

Which one will be the ideal usage? I need to support IE7 and higher versions.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

`document.getElementById('myRadio').checked` is a boolean value. It should be `true` or `false`

`document.getElementById('myRadio').checked = "checked";` casts the string to a boolean, which is true.

`document.getElementById('myRadio').checked = true;` just assigns `true` without casting.

Use `true` as it is marginally more efficient and is more intention revealing to maintainers.

Answer (score 18):

The element has both an attribute and a property named `checked`. The property determines the current state.

The attribute is a string, and the property is a boolean. When the element is created from the HTML code, the attribute is set from the markup, and the property is set depending on the value of the attribute.

If there is no value for the attribute in the markup, the attribute becomes `null`, but the property is always either `true` or `false`, so it becomes `false`.

When you set the property, you should use a boolean value:

```
document.getElementById('myRadio').checked = true;
```

If you set the attribute, you use a string:

```
document.getElementById('myRadio').setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
```

Note that setting the attribute also changes the property, but setting the property doesn't change the attribute.

Note also that whatever value you set the attribute to, the property becomes `true`. Even if you use an empty string or `null`, setting the attribute means that it's checked. Use `removeAttribute` to uncheck the element using the attribute:

```
document.getElementById('myRadio').removeAttribute('checked');
```

Comment: Good explanation between the property & attribute. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

The original `checked` attribute (HTML 4 and before) did not require a value on it - if it existed, the element was "checked", if not, it wasn't.

This, however is not valid for XHTML that followed HTML 4.

The standard proposed to use `checked="checked"` as a condition for true - so both ways you posted end up doing the same thing.

It really doesn't matter which one you use - use the one that makes most sense to you and stick to it (or agree with your team which way to go).

Comment: No. In HTML 4 and earlier it *did* require a value … it was the name that was optional. i.e. `checked="checked"` is the full version, but you can leave `checked="` and `"` off and just leave the value behind. (SGML can get *weird*!)

Comment: That said, the question is asking about the DOM property, not the HTML rules.

Comment: @Quentin - Fair enough, though that's almost an argument about semantics.

Answer (score 6):

`document.getElementById('myRadio')` returns you the DOM element, i'll reference it as `elem` in this answer.

`elem.checked` accesses the *property* named `checked` of the DOM element. This property is always a boolean.

When writing HTML you use `checked="checked"` in XHTML; in HTML you can simply use `checked`. When setting the attribute (this is done via `.setAttribute('checked', 'checked')`) you need to provide a value since some browsers consider an empty value being non-existent.

However, since you have the DOM element you have no reason to set the attribute since you can simply use the - much more comfortable - boolean property for it. Since non-empty strings are considered `true` in a boolean context, setting `elem.checked` to `'checked'` or anything else that is not a falsy value (even `'false'` or `'0'`) will check the checkbox. There is not reason not to use `true` and `false` though so you should stick with the proper values.

Answer (score 3):

`checked` attribute is a boolean value so `"checked"` value of other `"string"` except boolean `false` converts to `true`.

Any string value will be true. Also presence of attribute make it true:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked>
```

You can make it uncheked only making boolean change in DOM using JS.

So the answer is: they are equal.

[w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-checked)

Comment: You are confusing the JavaScript DOM property with the HTML attribute (and muddling in browser error recovery for good measure).