# Darkmode checkbox input get checked only from the second click

Tags: javascript, html, css, darkmode

When running on a browser, the switch below activates/disactivates darkmode from the first click, **but** get checked/un-checked only from the **second** click.

[**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10650233/checked-checked-vs-checked-true) Originally I used the `checked` property only and later added the `checked` attribute to try and fix the issue (as you can see- it didn't help).
It acts the same also in case the JavaScript handles the `checked` attribute only.

**The purpose is to have it work in a multiple pages site** (hence the `localStorage` involvment).

I failed to understand why it happens.

Any suggestions?

**all-pages.js:**

```js
const htmlTag = document.querySelector('html');
const switchBtn = document.querySelector('.slider');
const darkCheckbox = document.querySelector('.dark-cb');

function darkMode() {
  if (localStorage.getItem('dark') == 'true') {
    darkCheckbox.checked = true;
    darkCheckbox.setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
    htmlTag.classList.add('dark');
    switchBtn.classList.add('dark');
  } else {
    darkCheckbox.checked = false;
    darkCheckbox.removeAttribute('checked');
    htmlTag.classList.remove('dark');
    switchBtn.classList.remove('dark');
  }
}

switchBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  localStorage.setItem('dark', htmlTag.className.indexOf('dark') == -1);
  darkMode();
});


window.onload = darkMode();
```

**style.css:**

```css
html {
  min-height: 100%;
}

.switch {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}


/* Hide default HTML checkbox */

.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}


/* The slider */

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: skyblue;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: #FFFF66;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: darkblue;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1000px darkblue;
}

input:checked+.slider::before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}


/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round::before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.dark {
  filter: invert(1);
}
```

**index.html:**

```html
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <link href="./style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav id="nav-bar">
      <label class="switch">
            <input type="checkbox" class='dark-cb'>
            <span class="slider round" title="light/dark mode"></span>
          </label>
    </nav>
    <script src="all-pages.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: `window.onload = darkMode();` is supposed to be `window.onload = darkMode;`

Comment: Thanks, @ChrisG fixed. But it doen't solve the issue.

Comment: Where is `darkCheckbox`defined?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Sorry, it was ommited by mistake in the question. Added it now (it's in the global scope)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some modification solved the issue.

Slightly modified CSS:

```
.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 52px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

Modified JS:

```
const htmlTag = document.querySelector('html');
const switchBtn = document.querySelector('.slider');
const darkCheckbox = document.querySelector('.dark-cb');

function darkMode() {
  if (localStorage.getItem('dark') == 'true') {
    darkCheckbox.defaultChecked = true;
    htmlTag.classList.add('dark');
    switchBtn.classList.add('dark');
  } else {
    darkCheckbox.defaultChecked = false;
    htmlTag.classList.remove('dark');
    switchBtn.classList.remove('dark');
  }
}

darkCheckbox.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let isDark = (localStorage.getItem('dark') == 'true') ? 'false' : 'true';
  if (localStorage.getItem('dark') == null) {isDark = 'true';}
  localStorage.setItem('dark',isDark);
  darkMode();
});

window.onload = darkMode;
```

1. I changed the `localStorage.getItem('dark')` value to be accepted by the `isDark` variable
2. I used `.defaultChecked` instead of `.checked` for the input.
3. I made the `.addEventListnter()` be triggered by the `darkCheckbox`, not `switchBtn` (that is why I used `z-index: 100` on the CSS, to bring the input to the front).

Answer (score 1):

IF I understood correctly you are having problems with the fancy checkbox appearing to be checked upon first clicking but the toggling of classes to the HTML element etc works fine.
To that end I hope the following might prove useful.

Because of the restrictions imposed here with `Snippets` not being able to access `localStorage` I cannot create a `snippet` to demonstrate but perhaps this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RamRaider/yza9g0tp/5/) will help illustrate

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <style>
            /* variables */
            :root{
                --w:2rem;
                --h:2rem;
                --l:0rem;
                --t:0rem;
                --r:10rem;
                
                --sw:5rem;
                --sh:2rem;
                
                --pt:1rem;
                --pl:2rem;
            }


            html {
                min-height: 100%;
            }
            .switch {
                position:absolute;
                
                top:var(--pt);
                left:var(--pl);
                width:var(--sw);
                height:var(--sh);
            }


            /* Hide default HTML checkbox */
            .switch input {
                opacity:1;
                width:2rem;
                height:10rem;
            }
            .switch input {
              opacity: 0;
              width: 0;
              height: 0;
            }

            /* The slider */
            .slider {
                position:absolute;
                cursor:pointer;
                
                top:0;
                left:0;
                right:0;
                bottom:0;
                
                background-color:skyblue;
                transition:0.4s;
            }

            .slider::before {
                position:absolute;
                content:'';
                
                height:var(--h);
                width:var(--w);
                left:var(--l);
                bottom:var(--t);
                
                background-color:#FFFF66;
                transition:0.4s;
            }

            input:checked + .slider {
                background-color:darkblue;
            }

            input:focus + .slider {
                box-shadow:0 0 1000px darkblue;
            }

            input:checked + .slider::before {
                transform:translateX( calc( var(--sw) - var(--w) ) );
            }


            /* Rounded sliders */
            .slider.round {
                border-radius:var(--r);
            }
            .slider.round::before {
                border-radius:var(--r);
            }
            .dark {
                filter:invert(1);
            }
            
            /* debug */
            html.dark{
                background:gray;
                color:white;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav id='nav-bar'>
            <label class='switch'>
                <input type='checkbox' name='dark-cb' class='dark-cb'>
                <span class='slider round' title='light/dark mode'></span>
            </label>
        </nav>
        <script>
      
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
                const store='darkmode_toggle';
                const cn='dark';
                
                const html=document.querySelector('html');
                const bttn=document.querySelector('.slider');
                const chk=document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"][name="dark-cb"]');
                
                
                function darkMode() {
                    // get the stored value. This will be null if it does not exist.
                    let i=localStorage.getItem(store);
                    
                    // set the initial value if null.
                    if( i==null ){
                        localStorage.setItem(store,0);
                        i=Number(localStorage.getItem(store));
                    }else i=Number(i);
                    
                    
                    // if `darkMode` was invoked by a `click` event - toggle the saved value
                    if( typeof( arguments[0] )!='undefined' && arguments[0].type=='click' ){
                        localStorage.setItem( store, 1 - i );
                        i=Number(localStorage.getItem(store));
                    }
                    
                    
                    // set attributes and classes as appropriate to current state
                    switch(i){
                        case 1:
                            html.classList.add(cn)
                            bttn.classList.add(cn);
                            
                            // force the checkbox state on page load only
                            if( typeof( arguments[0] )=='undefined' )chk.checked=1;
                        break;
                        case 0:
                            html.classList.remove(cn)
                            bttn.classList.remove(cn);
                            if( html.classList.length==0 )html.removeAttribute('class');
                            if( bttn.classList.length==0 )bttn.removeAttribute('class');
                            
                            // force the checkbox state on page load only
                            if( typeof( arguments[0] )=='undefined' )chk.checked=0;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                
                bttn.addEventListener('click', darkMode );
                darkMode();
                
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Modified the `darkMode` function so that the checking / unchecking of the `checkbox` programmatically nowonly happens when there is no MouseEvent/Click. Also tweaked the CSS to use variables so that the layout can be modified quickly and programmatically if required.

Comment: Hi, thanks! In your solution it works on a **single page** site. However, the purpose is to have it work in a **multiple pages** site (hence the `localStorage` involvment). If testing on such a site- after moving to another page the darkmode toggles onload and then only toggles the darkmode from the second click. (the switch get checked/un-checked from the fist click as needed).

Comment: it should not `toggle` on page load. How can I emulate this effect to test for myself? Have a 2nd page with the same code in?

Comment: just tested with 2 pages - have seen a small issue. Will look at this tomorrow ~ seems like an easy fix

Comment: yes, and have an ‘<a>’ tag to link between the pages.

Comment: I think that is now resolved. Yesterday I could not see the wood for the trees as they say.. the obvious think I missed was the setting of the checkbox in the `darkMode` function... that should only have been called when there was no `click` because the actual physical click set the state of the checkbox anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I see what you mean. Please try this one:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Dark/Light Mode Switch</title>
    <style>
        :root {
            --primary-color: #302AE6;
            --secondary-color: #536390;
            --font-color: #424242;
            --bg-color: #fff;
            --heading-color: #292922;
        }

        [data-theme="dark"] {
            --primary-color: #9A97F3;
            --secondary-color: #818cab;
            --font-color: #e1e1ff;
            --bg-color: #161625;
            --heading-color: #818cab;
        }

        html {
            min-height: 100%;
        }

        body {
            background-color: var(--bg-color);
            color: var(--font-color);
            max-width: 90%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            font-size: calc(1rem + 0.25vh);
        }


        .switch {
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            left: 20px;
            width: 60px;
            height: 34px;
        }


        /* Hide default HTML checkbox */

        .switch input {
            opacity: 0;
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
        }


        /* The slider */

        .slider {
            position: absolute;
            cursor: pointer;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            background-color: #044660;
            -webkit-transition: .4s;
            transition: .5s;
        }

        .slider::before {
            position: absolute;
            content: "";
            height: 26px;
            width: 26px;
            left: 4px;
            bottom: 4px;
            background-color: #FFFF66;
            -webkit-transition: .4s;
            transition: .4s;
        }

        input:checked + .slider {
            background-color: darkblue;
        }

        input:focus + .slider {
            box-shadow: 0 0 1000px darkblue;
        }

        input:checked + .slider::before {
            -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
            -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
            transform: translateX(26px);
        }


        /* Rounded sliders */

        .slider.round {
            border-radius: 24px;
        }

        .slider.round::before {
            border-radius: 50%;
        }

        .dark {
            filter: invert(1);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<nav id='nav-bar'>
    <label class='switch' for="checkbox">
        <input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' id="checkbox" class='dark-cb'>
        <span class='slider round' title='Enable Dark Mode!'></span>
    </label>
</nav>

<div style="margin: 100px">
    Testing Dark/Light Mode Switch
</div>


<script>
    const toggleSwitch = document.querySelector('.switch input[type="checkbox"]');

    function switchTheme(e) {
        if (e.target.checked) {
            document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark');
            localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark'); //add this
        } else {
            document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'light');
            localStorage.setItem('theme', 'light'); //add this
        }
    }

    const currentTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme') ? localStorage.getItem('theme') : null;

    if (currentTheme) {
        document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', currentTheme);

        if (currentTheme === 'dark') {
            toggleSwitch.checked = true;
        }
    }

    toggleSwitch.addEventListener('change', switchTheme, false);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. This works, however it is too far from my current structure and will require too many canges to HTML, CSS and JS. I am trying to find the root cause to the issue

Comment: The reason was that your js code doesn't initialise the first window loaded condition of checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Change your darkMode function to the one below. Then your problem is solved!

```
function darkMode() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('dark') === 'false' ) {
        darkCheckbox.checked = false;
        darkCheckbox.removeAttribute('checked');
        htmlTag.classList.remove('dark');
        switchBtn.classList.remove('dark');
    } else {
        darkCheckbox.checked = true;
        darkCheckbox.setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
        htmlTag.classList.add('dark');
        switchBtn.classList.add('dark');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't see any effect by the suggsted change :\

Comment: I have tested it on my PC and it works as you wished. I checked again and it works well. Refresh the page and try it again please. You should see the reaction with the first click on the button, not with a double click like before the change.

Comment: Did you copy paste the modified function on the original one?

Comment: Yes. Please note that the purpose is to have it work in a multiple pages site (hence the `localStorage` involvment).