# innerHTML Assignment Prevents the Prior Logic to Execute Properly

Tags: javascript, html

I am dynamically creating a "div" element and a checkbox. If my code does not contain the `div.innerHTML += '<br>'` line (or any other line for that matter) as below, the logic setting the checkbox to true works properly. However, if I include the said line, the checkbox is not set to true, even if the data is true. Why would having this additional line create issues?

```
 div = document.createElement('div')
 var checkbox = document.createElement('input')
 checkbox.type = 'checkbox'
 if (data === true) {
    checkbox.checked = true
 } else {
    checkbox.checked = false
 }
 div.appendChild(checkbox)
 div.innerHTML += '<br>' // Line creating issues
 divArea.appendChild(div)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you assign: `checkbox.checked = true` you define the property (state of the checkbox check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10650394/1102574)).

When you use `div.innerHTML` it recreates ([replaces](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)) all the HTML inside div plus the one you adding. When HTML is re-created you lose `checked` state.

The best here is to set the `attribute` or add `br` via `insertAdjacentHTML()` or `createElement`.

```js
//via setAttribute()
var data = true;
var divArea = document.getElementById("divArea");
var div = document.createElement('div');
var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
checkbox.type = 'checkbox';

if (data === true) {
   checkbox.setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
}

div.appendChild(checkbox);
div.innerHTML += '<br>'; // Line creating issues
divArea.appendChild(div);
```

```html
<div id="divArea"></div>
```

```js
//via insertAdjacentHTML
var data = true;
var divArea = document.getElementById('divArea');
var div = document.createElement('div');
var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
if (data === true) {
   checkbox.checked = true;
} else {
   checkbox.checked = false;
}
div.appendChild(checkbox);
div.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<br>'); // Line creating issues
divArea.appendChild(div);
```

```html
<div id="divArea"></div>
```

```js
//via creatElement
var data = true;
var divArea = document.getElementById('divArea');
var div = document.createElement('div');
var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
if (data === true) {
   checkbox.checked = true;
} else {
   checkbox.checked = false;
}
div.appendChild(checkbox);
div.appendChild(document.createElement('br')); // Line creating issues
divArea.appendChild(div);
```

```html
<div id="divArea"></div>
```

[Difference](https://medium.com/@urgen.nyc/innerhtml-vs-insertadjacenthtml-afec74570afc) between `innerHTML` and `insertAdjacentHTML`

Answer (score 2):

You have a reference to a checkbox that exists in your div element. When you set `div.innerHTML += '<br>'` you overwrite the checkbox in your div element with a new checkbox and a br tag. Your expression means covert my element's contents to an html string, add `<br>` to the end, forget about your old contents, and create new contents from the new string.

Appending to the div will work, see the snippet.

```js
divArea = document.getElementById("div-area")
data = true
div = document.createElement('div')
 var checkbox = document.createElement('input')
 checkbox.type = 'checkbox'
 if (data === true) {
    checkbox.checked = true
 } else {
    checkbox.checked = false
 }
 div.appendChild(checkbox)
 div.appendChild(document.createElement('br'))
 divArea.appendChild(div)
```

```html
<div id="div-area">
```