# What is the correct way to use attributes in HTML5 video tag

Tags: html, video, attributes, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does it mean in HTML 5 when an attribute is a boolean attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139786/what-does-it-mean-in-html-5-when-an-attribute-is-a-boolean-attribute)

So I have seen it a lot of ways and appearently everyone here thinks w3schools is not trustworthy.

This:

```
<video controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay">
...
</video>
```

or this:

```
<video controls autoplay>
...
</video>
```

or even this:

```
<video controls="true" autoplay="true">
...
</video>
```

The true/false one makes the most sense to me, however, most I have seen work in all major browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are called boolean attributes on the W3C Html5 specification, which
proposes that the presence of a boolean attribute makes it true, and absence makes it false, like this:

```
<video controls autoplay>
```

but it also mentions that this could be equivalently written as:

```
<video controls=controls autoplay=autoplay> (values can be quoted also) or
<video controls="" autoplay="">
```

But specifically **forbids** "true" or "false" as attribute values:

```
The values "true" and "false" are not allowed on boolean attributes.
```

Also see http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-video-element.html#the-video-element and http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html for the video tag spec and the Html5 media API and events.

Comment: Great. Thank you. Sorry for the dup.