# How to remove an attribute in D3.js?

Tags: javascript, dom, attributes, d3.js

Can I in D3.JS remove an attribute? I've added it using `.attr("disabled", "disabled")` and now I am looking for something similar to jQuery's `.removeAttr("disabled", "disabled");` to remove it again. Useful for `<button>` and `<option>`. I've tried using the `.remove()` but that removes the entire object not the attribute.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

From the [API documentation for `attr`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_attr)

> A null value will remove the specified attribute

So it looks like you want `.attr('disabled', null)`.