# Add attributes without values using d3.js

Tags: html, d3.js

How could I add attributes without values using d3.js?

For example, how could I construct such an option:

```
<option value="" disabled selected>Select something...</option>
```

In this example the `disabled` and `selected` attributes have no value. And `value` attribute has a value of `""`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove an attribute in D3.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15322556/how-to-remove-an-attribute-in-d3-js)

Comment: Please do not edit your question to address comments. Comments go on the comments section. I rolled it back.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado, but it is not a comment. You can see clearly that the question is marked as a duplicate.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado, lol. Is it that now anyone can tell me that the question is just a duplicate without any explanations provided?

Comment: Yes, anyone with sufficient RP can vote to close, for right or wrong reasons. If you disagree with the person that left the comment regarding his/her vote, write another **comment** complaining about it, or take it to the meta... but don't edit your question to answer comments. On the other hand, if you have **additional information** relevant to the problem which can show to the user that your question is not a duplicate, then you should edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado, you deleted the **additional information** I provided.

Comment: @YaroslavTrofimov No, I didn't. Anyway, feel free to edit it the way you want, I won't edit this question again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For exactly these purposes you can use [`selection.property()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_property):

> Some HTML elements have special properties that are not addressable using attributes or styles, such as a form field’s text `value` and a checkbox’s `checked` boolean. Use this method to get or set these properties.

Your `<option>` can thus be constructed along the following lines:

```
d3.select("select")
  .append("option")
    .property("value", "")
    .property("selected", true)
    .property("disabled", true)
    .text("Select something...");
```

Comment: Does it mean that if I put `... .property("selected", false)`, then I will delete the attribute `selected` ?

Comment: Well, that's partly true. If you want to **delete** the property, you need to use `.property("selected", null)`. Technically, this is equivalent to setting it to `false` as the absence of the attribute represents a `false` value. See the spec for the definition of [boolean attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/infrastructure.html#boolean-attribute).