# CodeIgniter: input box using HTML5 required attribute

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a form in the **CodeIgniter** framework, and I want to use the **HTML "required"** attribute.
How can I do that?

```
$data = array(
              'name'        => 'username',
              'id'          => 'username',
              'value'       => 'johndoe',
              'maxlength'   => '100',
              'size'        => '50',
              'style'       => 'width:50%',
            );

echo form_input($data);
```

The result needed:

```
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="johndoe" 
required maxlength="100" size="50" style="width:50%" />
```

Comment: Not really familiar with codeigniter but can't you just do `'required' => 'required'`?

Comment: please make it ans.. i need to give you +1

Comment: Looks like somebody has already posted it, no point duplicating the answer :p

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to add it to the array.

```
$data = array(
              'name'        => 'username',
              'id'          => 'username',
              'value'       => 'johndoe',
              'maxlength'   => '100',
              'size'        => '50',
              'style'       => 'width:50%',
              'required' => 'required'
 );

echo form_input($data);
```

Comment: thaanx.. it solved .. but in past or present i doesn't read "  required=required ".
i always read "  required ". So i asked question.

Comment: You can use empty string as a value for `required` attribute ([as per](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4140263/1073003)) as well.