# How can i put HTML5 required field using form_input() function in Codeigniter framework

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-form-helper

I am new in codeigniter.But now i am developing a  project using codeigniter.
My Html code like this:

```
<input type="text" class="get_started_frm_reg" name="first_name" required />
```

Now i want to convert it through function form_input() function.I wrote my code like that

```
$first_name=array(
     "name"=>"first_name",
     "class"=>"get_started_frm_reg",
     "type"=>"text"
);
```

But i don't understand how can i put required field.Please help me.

Answer (score 5):

```
$first_name=array("name"=>"first_name",
               "class"=>"get_started_frm_reg",
               "type"=>"text",
               "required"=>"required");
```

This is working

Comment: You can use empty string as a value for `required` attribute ([as per](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4140263/1073003)) as well.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend the following:

```
form_input('first_name', $value, 'class="get_started_frm_reg" required');

// if you don't want to pass a variable for value, pass 'null'
form_input('first_name', null, 'class="get_started_frm_reg" required');
```

The above will output exactly how you were asking in your question.

I like using this method better then passing an array to `form_input` because you have better control over boolean input values, like `required`. Also, you don't need to pass `text="type"` since it is the default on `form_input`.

Answer (score 0):

The best is to use it like this:

```
<?=form_input(['name'=>'first_name', 'class'=>'get_started_frm_reg'],'','required');?>
```

Produces:

```
<input type="text" class="get_started_frm_reg" name="first_name" required />
```