# Uncheck a checkbox using CSS

Tags: html, css, checkbox

For those not familiar, the checked attribute for a checkbox will accept any input as a sign to check the box.  in fact, it doesnt need any text.  so all these will check the box

```
<input type="checkbox" checked />
<input type="checkbox" checked="false">
<input type="checkbox" checked="">
<input type="checkbox" checked="0">
```

all those WILL check the box.

My problem is i am being handed a checked box, and need to uncheck it.  I cant just change its value - that still makes it checked.  i need to nuke it from orbit.  This is incredibly easy to do with javascript or jQuery, but the site does not allow any of that in my CSS.

I read a list of about 100 attributes and how to reset them - auto, normal, 0, inherit, et cetera, but 'checked' was not on the list, and i tried all of those and anything i could think of, and this checkmark wont die.

Comment: `checked` is not a `style attribute` so that you can't modify it by using css

Comment: Just to make this clearer - the `checked` attribute is a [boolean attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139786/what-does-it-mean-in-html-5-when-an-attribute-is-a-boolean-attribute), which means its very presence in the markup indicates a true value, regardless of the "value" it's given.

Answer (score 15):

The simple answer is **NO**, CSS cannot help you uncheck the checkbox..

**BUT**

You can use CSS to **detect** whether the `input` element is checked or not by using `:checked` and `:not(:checked)` ..

Test Case : <kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jYAfC/)</kbd>

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" checked />
        <label for="">Checked</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox">
        <label for="">Unchecked</label>
    </li>
        <li>
        <input type="checkbox" checked>
        <label for="">Checked Again</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
input:checked + label {
    color: green;
}

input:not(:checked) + label {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: By definition it *shouldn't*.

Comment: The question is about unchecking a checkbox, so it’s not relevant to suggest methods that just use the checkness state in styling. It can even be somewhat confusing.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I've the word **detect** written in bold, should be enough for a user to understand that still CSS cannot uncheck a checkbox ... :)

Answer (score 4):

CSS is not for dom manipulation, its for dom styling and arrangements, You can not set dom attributes from css but you can check for css conditions and set styles. :)

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to check/uncheck checkbox using jquery. Here is the code:

```
$('#textCheckbox').attr('checked', true); // Enable CheckBox
$('#textCheckbox').attr('checked', false); // Disable CheckBox

After alteration, following will be the output of your input field

<input type="checkbox" id="textCheckbox" checked="checked" /> <!-- Checked -->
<input type="checkbox" id="textCheckbox" /> <!-- Unchecked -->
```

Fill free to mark correct answer if you think this is what you are looking at..

Comment: I'm afraid the OP specifically states *This is incredibly easy to do with javascript or jQuery, but the site does not allow any of that in my CSS*. Also, even if this was relevant, you should be using the `.prop()` method and not `.attr()`.

Answer (score 0):

Question was asked 6 years ago but it should be noted you *can* give the **appearance** of an unchecked checkbox with CSS:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
html, body { padding: 1rem; }
input { display: none; }
label, label::after, hr, hr::after {
  display: block;
  overflow: visible;
  position: relative;
  transform: scale( 0.8 );
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  border-style: none;
  border-radius: 0.125rem;
  box-shadow: 0rem 0rem 0rem 0.0625rem #666;
  content: '';
}
label::after, hr, hr::after {
  transform: scale( 1.15 );
  background-color: #07f;
  box-shadow: none;
}
label::after { display: none; }
label:hover { box-shadow: 0rem 0rem 0rem 0.0625rem #222; }
label:hover::after { background-color: #06e; }
label:active::after { background-color: #18f; }
```

```html
<style>
  hr, hr::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0.5rem;
    z-index: 1;
    transform: rotate( 40deg );
    width: 0.225rem;
    height: 0.9rem;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  hr::after {
    top: 0.6rem; left: -0.17rem;
    transform: rotate( -90deg );
    height: 0.4rem;
  }
  #one:checked ~ [ for='one' ]::after { display: block; }
  
  [ for='two' ]::after { display: block; }
  
  #one:checked ~ [ for='two' ]::after { display: none; }
</style>

<input type='checkbox' id='one'>
<input type='checkbox' id='two' checked>

<p>check me</p>
<label for='one'> <hr> </label>

<br>

<p>to uncheck me</p>
<label for='two'> <hr> </label>
```