# Show checkbox as if unchecked when printing?

Tags: css, media-queries

I have a website with a list of checkboxes that can be used for printing as well. Though when printing it should print a clean slate, not the current state of the checkboxes on the website. However, I don't want to clear the state on the page itself, only on the printed version.

So is it possible to **visually** remove the tick from checkboxes in CSS?

Something like:

```
@media print
{
    input[type=checkbox]
    {
        tick: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: In print you want just the border square box which can be manually ticked, right? So in print CSS you might just change the design of check boxes so that you hide the original checkbox html , doesn't matter if checked or not. And then just style or show a square border box , good enough for a checkbox looking box for printing. Will this work? As via CSS you can change design and not the html state of the forms.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uncheck a checkbox using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24135355/uncheck-a-checkbox-using-css)

Comment: @Mohsin So essentially you're suggesting just hiding the checkbox in css, and drawing a box in it's place? That should be possible with like a `:before` selector or something. I'll try that :D

Comment: @SebastianBrosch I don't think so, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Exactly, using :before selector you can insert something there good enough for printing needs. Glad you are going to try this idea. Good luck :D

Comment: I have copied it to answer also if it works please mark it resolved. Good luck

Comment: @Mohsin I tried this: `input[type=checkbox]::after{ content: "[]"; }` however that does nothing. It doew work with `div::after{ ... }`, but of course places the boxes everywhere then.

Comment: Sorry I am on mobile so cannot try code , but you may need to add position absolute and top, right margin to get it right. Also add border and background to get more control of it. Will reply tomorrow if you cannot get it resolved by then. Late here.

Comment: Why do you want to show a blank slate on print? What's the point of printing a blank form after someone spends time to fill it out? It is currently sounding like an X/Y problem.

Comment: @TylerH As i understand not whole form is being print in blank slate, just the last consent checkbox which most of the time in real situation is needed with whole form filled in computer but last consent line with TICK (Manual hand marked) is done on printed form for physical record keep...

Comment: @Mohsin If the last checkbox needs to checked with a pen by hand, then it shouldn't be getting filled out via the computer. It should be hidden on the computer via a `screen` media query and shown via a `print` media query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest following approach.

In print you want just the border square box which can be manually ticked, right?

So in print CSS you might just change the design of check boxes so that you hide the original checkbox html , doesn't matter if checked or not. And then just style or show a square border box  using some pseudo selector like : before :after, , good enough for a checkbox looking box for printing.

As via CSS you can change design and not the html state of the forms. So in media query of print or print style sheet only option is designing, styling...

Comment: Sadly it seems you can't use `:after` on inputs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587669/can-i-use-a-before-or-after-pseudo-element-on-an-input-field I'll have to do some restructuring, and maybe just add an element I only show when printing.

Comment: I see. Good find. Yes hiding the checkbox and then you can target any nearby div or element which. I am sure you will get it working. Good luck

Comment: By the way there is :checked selector also you can use to hide only checked checkboxes.