# Keeping HTML boolean attributes in their original form when parsing with Jsoup

Tags: java, html, boolean, jsoup

When parsing the following HTML with [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/):

```java
String html = "<iframe allowfullscreen></iframe>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(html);
System.out.println(doc.body().html());
```

I get the following output:

```
<iframe allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

Even if it must have the same meaning ([source](http://www.w3.org/TR/html/infrastructure.html#boolean-attributes)), is there any way to tell Jsoup to keep the boolean attributes in their original form (i.e. the one in the input, `allowfullscreen` instead of `allowfullscreen=""` in the example)?

Comment: When you say "original form," there are many different ways that the attribute can be written: `allowfullscreen`, `allowfullscreen=""`, `allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"`, `allowfullscreen=AllowFullScreen`, and any other variation in capitalization you like. Is your goal to preserve what's in the input, or to always output just `allowfullscreen`? (The good news is that `attr` will give you the value it has [`""`, `"allowfullscreen"`, `"AllowFullScreen"`, ...], but I don't think you can differentiate between `allowfullscreen` and `allowfullscreen=""`.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, by original form, I mean the one in the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think there's a simple setting to control this. If there were, you'd expect to find it in [`Document.OutputSettings`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Document.OutputSettings.html).

The good news, as I said in the comment, is that the original form of the attribute *is* retained and available via `attr`, with the exception that you can't tell the difference between `allowfullscreen` on its own and `allowfullscreen=""`.

So you *could* serialize the document yourself, modulo not being able to tell that one difference. Alternately, as Jsoup is open source, you could add a `Document.OutputSettings` setting for this (and possibly a modification in the parser that lets you tell the difference between the two cases above) and update the logic in the `html` and related methods to respect the setting, ideally by forking [the project](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/), making the change, making tests for the change, and doing a pull request. :-) Not probably the answer one would have liked, but the great thing about OS is that you can scratch your own itch and improve the project in the process.

Answer (score 0):

By reading the javadoc of [`Document.OutputSettings`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Document.OutputSettings.html), I think that `Document.OutputSettings.Syntax.xml` is what you need:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment("<ol reversed><li>one</li></ol>");
doc.outputSettings().syntax(Syntax.xml);

System.out.println(doc.body().html());
```

Prints:

```
<ol reversed="">
 <li>one</li>
</ol>
```

The default (I think it is `Document.OutputSettings.Syntax.html`) would be:

```
<ol reversed>
 <li>one</li>
</ol>
```

As mentioned in this question [What does it mean in HTML 5 when an attribute is a boolean attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4139786/91497) with HTML Boolean attributes, semantically these three forms are the same:

```
<ol reversed>
<ol reversed="">
<ol reversed="reversed">
```

*(Tested with Version `1.10.2` of JSoup)*