# ASP.NET MVC 5 renders different bool value for hidden input

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Given the following viewmodel:

```
public class FooViewModel
{
    public bool IsBoolValue { get; set; }
}
```

and this view:

```
<input type="hidden" id="Whatever" data-something="@Model.IsBoolValue" value="@Model.IsBoolValue" />
```

The output of the hidden input field is this:

`<input type="hidden" id="Whatever" data-something="True" value="value">`

How come the `value` attribute is not set to`True`, but the `data-something` attribute is?

Is there a change in MVC 5 that would cause this, since in my MVC 4 apps this problem does not occur.

Comment: First you should indicate the name of your input to IsBoolValue , doig this this the value of input will be set by mvc, now model binding is not working, if you will indicate the name of input to be IsBoolValue  model binding will work.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I think I've figured it out.

I believe the Razor viewengine is adhering to the HTML 5 way of setting boolean attributes, as described here:

[What does it mean in HTML 5 when an attribute is a boolean attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139786/what-does-it-mean-in-html-5-when-an-attribute-is-a-boolean-attribute)

In HTML 5, a bool attribute is set like this:

`<input readonly />`

or

`<input readonly="readonly" />`

So the Razor viewengine takes your model's bool value and will render (in my case) the `value` attribute if `Model.IsBoolValue` is `true`. Otherwise, if it's `false` then the `value` attribute is not rendered at all.

EDIT:

As mentioned Zabavsky in the comments, to force the value of True or False to appear in the `value` attrbiute, simple use `ToString()`:

`<input type="hidden" value="@Model.BoolProperty.ToString()" />`

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that the solution to this is simply call `ToString()` on the property: `value="@Model.IsBoolValue.ToString()"`.

Answer (score 1):

```cs
<div class="field_warp_hidden">
    <input type="checkbox" asp-for="ShowGoogleCaptcha" checked="@Model.ShowGoogleCaptcha" value="@Model.ShowGoogleCaptcha"/>
</div>
```

can set `field_wrap_hidden` is `display:none;`

**`checked` and `value` must be set**

---

**2024/03/05 Additional answers**

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.RememberMe, new { @class = "form-check-input" })
```

This will handle the content.

Answer (score 1):

I was using the hidden field in a partial view and I got an error when I used .ToString()
alternative option was to specify the value property explicitly even after specifying asp-for

```
<input type="hidden" value="@Model.TargetmarketsToChangeAvailability[i].Available" asp-for="TargetmarketsToChangeAvailability[i].Available" />
```