# how to pass bool value to view from controller as a model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html

```html
@moelname
@{
  
    Layout = "";
}


<input type="hidden" id="" value="@Model.modelproperty" />
```

here value not coming give your suggestions

Comment: You can use `ViewBag`

Comment: Use `@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.modelproperty)`

Comment: Eh can you give us your code for the controller as well?

Comment: This code does not look right at all.

Comment: If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 5):

This should be sufficient

**Model**

```
public class MyModel
{
    public bool MyBool { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult MyController()
{
    return View(new MyModel {MyBool = true});
}
```

**View**

```
@model MyModel
<input value="@Model.MyBool.ToString()" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use @Model.modelproperty.ToString() to get it right.
Please refer this: [ASP.NET MVC 5 renders different bool value for hidden input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28849729/asp-net-mvc-5-renders-different-bool-value-for-hidden-input)