# How to add html text inside tag?

Tags: javascript, html, tags

I am wondering how I can add html text inside tag using javascript. Not class or id that can be added with classList.add('') or setAttribute.
For example, I want to add html text 'disabled' inside the button tag like this:
`<button class="button is-danger" id="reset">Reset</button>` to
`<button class="button is-danger" id="reset" **disabled**>Reset</button>`

What would be the code for javascript? Thank you very much in advance

Edit: Disabled is an attribute

Comment: so what you actually whant is to disbale the button is it right ?

Comment: Is that ok if you set value for that attribute? like `btnEl.setAttribute("disabled", true)`

Comment: I didn't know disabled was an attribute - thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabled too is an attribute. Just writing disabled is the same as defaulting it to true.[disabled](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_disabled.asp)

If you want to add a custom attribute to pick you can and should refer to data attributes here:[custom attributes](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_data-.asp)

As an example, you can add these attributes via simple dom-manipulation using setAttribute itself.[setting an attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp)

Answer (score 0):

`disabled` is also an attribute i.e boolean attribute. If the attribute is present irrespective of the value, its value is always true if any boolean attribute is present. [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139786/what-does-it-mean-in-html-5-when-an-attribute-is-a-boolean-attribute)

```js
const first = document.querySelector("#first");
const second = document.querySelector("#second");
const third = document.querySelector("#third");
const fourth = document.querySelector("#fourth");

second.addEventListener('click', () => {
  first.setAttribute('disabled', true);
})

third.addEventListener('click', () => {
  first.setAttribute('disabled', false);
})

fourth.addEventListener('click', () => {
  first.removeAttribute('disabled');
})
```

```html
<button id="first"> Hello world </button>
<button id="second"> click to disable </button>
<button id="third"> click to disable </button>

<p> If you want to enable the button then you have to remove the attribute completely. Setting the value to false doesn't enable it</p>
<button id="fourth"> click to enable </button>
```