# How to swap a disabled option DOM element to enabled?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, xhtml

I have a list with enabled and disabled option. I do know how to disable an option element but what I don't know how to enable it again.

```
<select size="1" id="x">
  <option value="47" disabled="disabled">Value 47</option>
  ...


selectElement.options[i].disabled = 'disabled';
// ... how to enable?
```

It should be done with Plain Javascript and no JavaScript Framework. (I wish I could use Prototype or a similar framework but I cannot introduce one of them.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`setAttribute`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-F68F082) and [`removeAttribute`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-6D6AC0F9):

```
selectElement.options[i].setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
selectElement.options[i].removeAttribute("disabled");
```

Comment: 1.5 minutes... Thank you for your very quick help!

Comment: IE doesn't like this very much, see Bobince's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706384/boolean-html-attributes/707702#707702).

Answer (score 3):

The DOM object's *property* is a boolean value, that should be set to `true` or `false`:

```
selectElement.options[i].disabled = false;
```

Also see [Boolean HTML Attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706384/boolean-html-attributes).